# Uploadify Button Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, uploadify, swfobject

I don't know if something in my computer is blocking swf or what but Uploadify button is not displaying in my application even not on their website http://www.uploadify.com/demos/.

It would be great if someone could guide me how to fix the problem.

Comment: you have to be a little more specific on what is your problem or are you just trying to generate traffic through your page?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @DIEGOCARRASCAL . I fixed the error as it was the browser blocking flash to get run.